# Rename a variable from a list in R (no list or dataframe possible)

Tags: r

I am attempting to create a number of variables/values, each with a very unique set of data (called from an exterior R program) that unfortunately cannot be contained within a table or list. How can I iterate along a list of filenames to name each of these files?

I am already iterating through a for loop indexing from 1:3 (in this example), and I have a list of files in a data.frame:

```
filenames <- [file_name_1, file_name_2, file_name_33]

for(i in 1:nrow(filenames)){

#How do I name these files without typing in 1,2, and 33 manually? 
#Again they cannot be saved as a list or dataframe?
file_name_1 <- Exterior_complex_function(i)
file_name_2 <- Exterior_complex_function(i)
file_name_33 <- Exterior_complex_function(i)
}
```

I wish I could save this as a list, it would be much easier!

For everyone's information, this is the error I get when I try to use a list:

```
  object of type 'S4' is not subsettable
```

Comment: `sapply(filenames, Exterior_complex_function, simplify = FALSE)`?

Answer (score 0):

sapply/lapply will be helpful.

```
lapply(filenames, Exterior_complex_function)
```

if you want to pass the indexes then use this

```
lapply(seq(filenames), Exterior_complex_function)
```

https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/lapply.html

Comment: I'm not sure if that will work - since I'll need to iterate through the for loop with the "i" index through an existing dataframe to pull specific values. I was hoping I could either embed the naming within the for-loop, or generate the variable names outside of the loop and then call them within as I increase the index?

Answer (score 0):

Literally the only change you need to make to keep using for loops is to index the list and not via a sequence:

```r
filenames <- list("a", "b", "c")
for (file in filenames) print(file)
#> [1] "a"
#> [1] "b"
#> [1] "c"
```

You might also find functions from the `*apply` family useful as others suggested.

Comment: But if I `print(file)` I cannot assign my function to said file? That's where my confusion comes in

Comment: Where I've written `print(file)`, you can substitute any expression you like, including your `Exterior_complex_function`. Your code would just look like `for (file in filenames) Exterior_complex_function(file)`

Comment: But in this instance, I would not be calling the file to run the `exterior_complex_function` - I am attempting to write to said file. That's what is confusing to me at this point?

Answer (score 0):

```
filenames <- c("file_name_1", "file_name_2", "file_name_33")
tmp_list <- list()

for(i in 1:nrow(filenames)){
  tmp_list[filenames[i]] <- Exterior_complex_function(i)
}
```

Maybe it would work.